# Could someone help with me LaTeX ? I don't know why it isn't compiling

Tags: pdftex, compiling

I am new to LaTeX and i guess computer science in general. I am trying to generate a pdf with an image. I am having a lot of problems. I use MiKTeX 2.8

Here is what I entered

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document} 
\includegraphics{Reinhard}
\end{document}
```

I then hit the check button "pdfLaTeX" and it tells me it can't.

I am sure that the picture "Reinhard.jpg" is only my desktop.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Do you get any error messages? (You'll find these in the .log file.) What editor are you using? How exactly does it tell you that it can't? (Btw: Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean "it tells me it can't".  Try moving the jpg file to the same directory as the .tex file.

Comment: (Jak wanted to post this as edit to the question) @Peter, it worked! I thought MikTeX would search the file. I guess that isn't true.

Answer (score 6):

Your example is working for me. Make sure:

- that your image is named as `*.jpg` or `*.JPG` (pdfLaTeX is case sensitive);
- that your image is in the same folder as your `*.tex` file (or a folder in which LaTeX is searching for your file);
- that your image is really a jpeg file.