# Does anyone know what the other files that come with compiling are?

Tags: compiling, auxiliary-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent pdflatex from writing a bunch of files.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11123/prevent-pdflatex-from-writing-a-bunch-of-files)

Whenever I hit "compile" on MikTeX 2.8, I get a bunch of files I don't need like .aux, notepad files.

Is there a way to permanently tell MikTeX to stop giving me those files?

Comment: Assuming you're the same jak as http://math.stackexchange.com/users/21696/jak, i.e. the one who asked http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40307/4012, you should make a request at [meta] that your unregistered [mathematics.se] account be merged into your registered account.

Comment: Those files are needed. Information such as document internal references, table of contents entries etc. are stored in them. This is e.g. the reason why you have to compile several times to get a correct table of contents. one run colltects the entries and writes them to the toc file, the next run reads this file. I thik there is a way in MikTeX to write them in another folder, but the best way is to simply accept them. Most editors can clean a projct. So after you have your final pdf, the help files can be removed to keep your folder tidy

Comment: I like to have these files in a subdirectory named `latex` and copy the pdf to the folder containing the pdf with `cp %.pdf ../%.pdf`

Comment: @MartinH: I think you're talking about http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7272/4012.